# How to get rid of black lines in top screen [ubuntu 12.10]?

Tags: drivers, ati

I have recently started with installing ubuntu 12.10 (x64) next to my windows 8 (x64) install. But since installing the amd proprietary drivers I got weird black horizontal lines in top of the screen. See the 11sec video I made with my phone to know exactly what I mean:
http://youtu.be/OULpUYKPjj0

I had to install the proprietary drivers because with the opensource drivers I couldent login after first restart from fresh installation. I only got a black screen and a mouse.

This are my specs:
Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3 (rev. 1.3) 
AMD radeon hd 6950 
Dell UltraSharp U2312HM (connected with DVI)

I currently run the latest beta drivers from amd, but with the stable I had the same problem..

The strange thing is when I boot the computer, I get the black lines. But I found out that when I log out, and log back in, the black lines are gone! This however is not really an ideal situation.

**How can I fix this problem to completely get rid of these black lines?**

Comment: I got the same issue, it doesn't occur every time, haven't find out what causes it yet. I think it is simply bug in the drivers and there won't be a simple solution.

Comment: It looks similar when I have installed "Pardus 2011" on my Machine (Now using Fedora 17). This is very strange. I think it is a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on "Tear Free Desktop" (Catalyst Control Center -> Display Options -> Tear Free) seems to make the dashes less frequent.